# how to create dynamically datepickers in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker

on my angularjs application i show a modal window to edit an event and add/remove event dates(i use bootstrap datepicker and timepicker).

the event has some fixed dates, i dont have problem with that because i have them created first and i use them on ng-model (of the datepicker & timepicker).

**the problem is when the user press the add button to add new event dates dynamically, i dont have date variable to assign to the ng-model of the datepicker** .

**what i do to achieve that:**

1. inside `.controller('ModalEditEventP4ctrl',..` i manipulate the modal window(edit event).here i have a an empty object that i use it to add new eventdates into the directive `addNewDate`.
   `$scope.datesObj = {}`
2. **the add new eventdate button is a directive, where i pass a dates array object from the controller. Inside the directive i create new dates objects and push them on the array, so as to assign it into the html template**:

   ```
   .directive('addNewDate', function($compile){
     return {
       restrict: 'AE',
       scope: {
           onClick: '&',
           dyndatesObj: '='
       },
       link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
           element.bind('click', function () {                    
           /*1. here i create new date object and push it on the array */
               scope.dyndatesObj.push({dynDateStart:new Date(),dynDateEnd:new Date(),dtStatus:'1'});

              /*2. get the last item */
               var items = $(".row.basicDates").length-1;

               /*3. compile another directive 'newDateBlock'*/
               /* and pass it into the DOM*/
               /* the directive it is compiled but the datepickers are empty*/
               $('.row.basicDates:eq('+items+')').append($compile("<new-date-block />")(scope));
               scope.$apply();
           });
       }
     }
    })
   ```
3. **the directive `newDateBlock` that has the DOM elements which i compile it through the ebove directive is this:**

   ```
      .directive('newDateBlock', function(){
           return {
               restrict: 'AE',
               scope: {
                   onClick: '&',
                   myDate:'='
               },
               templateUrl: 'assets/modules/part4/templates/addNewDate.tpl.html',
               link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                   element.bind('click', function () {
                       console.log('inside directive');
                   });
               }
           }
       });
   ```
4. **the template file addNewDate.tpl.html**(i dont show it all). everything works ok , except from the datepickers that ,although i assign them **ng-model= datesObj[datesObj.length-1][dynDateStart]**, they are empty.

   ```
   <div class="row" >   
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-4" style="padding-left: 0;">
           <label>Start Date</label>
           <label>Start Time</label>
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-8" style="padding-left: 0;">
           <p class="input-group">
               <input type="text" class="form-control" style="width:100px"
                      datepicker-popup="{{format}}"
                    /*ng-model seems not to work*/
                      ng-model="datesObj[datesObj.length-1][dynDateStart]"
                      is-open=""
                      datepicker-options="dateOptions"
                      ng-required="true"
                      close-text="Close"/>
         <span class="input-group-btn" style="float:left">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="">
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
          </button>
         </span>
           </p>
           <timepicker ng-model="" ng-change="changed()" hour-step="1" minute-step="10" show-meridian="false"></timepicker>
       </div>
   </div>
   ```

[image]
it seems that the value inside the ng-model is not compiled , i dont know exactly what is the problem. any help would be appreciated.

to be more specific, i get the error (on the browser) that says:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'initDate' of undefined
    at link (http://.../bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js:8:23435)
    at http://.../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:70:141
    at $ (http://.../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:70:197)
    at B (http://..../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:59:255)
    at g (http://..../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:51:335)
    at g (http://..../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:51:352)
    at g (http:/..../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:51:352)
    at g (http://.../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:51:352)
    at g (http://..../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:51:352)
    at g (http://.../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:51:352) <input type="text" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-isolate-scope" style="width:100px" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="datesObj[0].dynDateStart" is-open="" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close">
```

Answer (score 0):

After many hours and too many tests **i quited the directives option and i made it work with functions inside the controller where i $compile the whole html template each time i add new date ,with ng-repeat , like refresh the whole DOM**, i just keep the html template because it works perfect.

what i did:

**1. inside my controller i created the addNewDate() function:**

```
$scope.addNewDate = function(){
       //i push the new item inside my events.eventDates object and not in another array object as previously
        $scope.eventmodal.eventDates.push({eventStartDate:new Date(),eventEndDate:new Date(),dateStatus:'1'});
            $templateRequest('/assets/modules/part4/templates/addNewDate.tpl.html').then(function(html){

            // Convert the html to an actual DOM node
            var template = angular.element(html);

            // clear completely(not append) the previous block of dates and add the new ones
            $('.basicDatesBlock').html(template);

            // finally $compile the template and show it.
            $compile(template)($scope);
        });
    };
```

**2. my addNewDate.tpl.html i use the ng-repeat to show all the eventDates (the old + the new ones) like this:**

```
<div class="row basicDates" ng-repeat="eventdate in eventmodal.eventDates track by $index" ng-show="eventdate.dateStatus == 1">
<!-- start date -->
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4" style="padding-left: 0;">
            <label>Start Date*</label>
            <label>Start Time</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8" style="padding-left: 0;">
            <p class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" style="width:100px"
                       datepicker-popup="{{format}}"
                       ng-model="eventdate.eventStartDate"
                       is-open="openIndex[$index]"
                       datepicker-options="dateOptions"
                       ng-required="true"
                       close-text="Close"/>
          <span class="input-group-btn" style="float:left">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="openme($index)">
               <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
           </button>
          </span>
            </p>
            <timepicker ng-model="eventdate.eventStartDate" ng-change="changed()" hour-step="1" minute-step="10" show-meridian="false"></timepicker>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- end date -->
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5" style="width:31.6%;padding-right:0;">
            <label>End Date*</label>
            <label>End Time</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <p class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" style="width:100px"
                       datepicker-popup="{{format}}"
                       ng-model="eventdate.eventEndDate"
                       is-open="openIndex[$index]"
                       datepicker-options="dateOptions"
                       ng-required="true"
                       close-text="Close"/>
                    <span class="input-group-btn" style="float:left">
                       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="openme($index)">
                           <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
                       </button>
                    </span>
            </p>
            <!-- i show the '+' button only for the first row-->
            <div style="float:right" ng-show="$index==0">
                <div class="plusCircle" style="margin-top:15px">
                    <!--<div class="plusSymbol" add-new-date  dyndates-obj = datesObj>+</div>-->
                    <div class="plusSymbol" ng-click="addNewBasicDate()">+</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- i show the 'X' button only for 2nd row and greater-->
            <div style="float:right" ng-show="$index>0">
                <div class="plusCircle" style="margin-top:15px">
                    <div class="plusSymbol">x</div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <timepicker ng-model="eventdate.eventEndDate" ng-change="changed()" hour-step="1" minute-step="10" show-meridian="false"></timepicker>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]
*And that's it. i tried to make myself clear , i hope it helps other guys with similar problems.*